# Swift ImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not fired

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the `ImagePickerController`, to grab a profile image. The user has a button. The button triggers the CamRoll function. When the button is clicked, the normal `ImagePickerViewController` appears, but the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` isn't called. In an earlier version of Swift/Xcode, the same code was called. This is my code.

```
import UIKit

class AnnonseViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var Image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@IBAction func CamRoll(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.delegate = self

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    let imageSize = image.size
    let width = imageSize.width
    let height = imageSize.height

    if width != height {
        let newDimensions = min(width,height)
        let widthOffset = (width - newDimensions) / 2
        let heightOffset = (height - newDimensions) / 2

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newDimensions, height: newDimensions), false, 0.0)

        image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: -widthOffset, y: -heightOffset), blendMode: .copy, alpha: 1.0)

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()! as UIImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))

    _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))

    let smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    Image.image = smallImage

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Why isn't the code called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct delegate method of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in Swift 3 for  `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` is as follow.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

}
```

You can check [Apple Documentations](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate) on `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 the method again has a different signature, replacing String with UIImagePickerController.InfoKey:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){

}
```