# cannot Use the "used photo" in IOS swift UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8

I'm new to swift... 
in fact I'm new to Any Apple products. so basically I'm trying to learn how to build and aircraft while trying to fly and learn how to fly it as well. When this disclaimer is out there I'd like some help ;)

My issue is that I cannot get UIImagePickerController to return with an image to me after I've taken one with the Camera. I think I'm missing something fundamental or at least something important to make it work ;) 
But I cannot for the life of me figure out where I'm doing it wrong.

this is what I think is the relevant parts of my ViewController however do ask if you feel I'm leaving something important out:

```
 @IBAction func shootPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {

        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {
        noCamera()
    }
}



    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage;
    myImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

    myImageView.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)

}
```

I must confess I do not know what version of swift I'm using. I'm assuming the latest because I just updated the MacBook Pro until it couldn't do any more. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 and I'm testing this on a IPhone with IOS 10.2.1 I think it's a IPhone 7s.

Any help is appreciated

**Edit:**
I'm setting that in this function if that is the wrong place I will move it I just cannot figure out to where. ?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    picker.delegate = self
}
```

I'm made aware that this might be a duplicate of another question however when I click to that one they are handling the photo library.

I'm trying to handle the camera and I'm having a issue with returning the image to my imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])...

what they talk about doesn't seem to be working for me and they are using things that I've been told is depricated.

**edit 2:**

this is how I initialise the picker object as well as how the class is defined

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()


    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
```

Comment: did you forgot to add delegate `picker.delegate = delegate` ?

Comment: Before adding `present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)` you need to set you controller as delegate, so that you can get call backs. Add `picker.delegate = self` , it will hit your `func imagePickerController(..)`

Comment: @Priyal if that is what I need to do then where I've tried it two places now one as described in my edit and the other I've tried it inside the shootPhoto method

Comment: @ConstantinSaulenco I did that before as described in the edit. but I also tried moving it to the shootPhoto method. none of them makes my photo appear

Comment: @Helbo how are you initalizing 'picker' object ?

Comment: @Helbo The problem is you signature of delegate method is changed in Swift 3 so add proper delegate like this answer of my http://stackoverflow.com/a/40480876/6433023 So replace your method with this one also don't forgot to remove private prefix from method.

Comment: @NiravD hmm will try that right away :)

Comment: @NiravD that worked thanks a lot you are my hero

Comment: @Helbo Welcome mate, glad my answer works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                myImageView.image = image
         } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            myImageView.image = image
         }
        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        self.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: just tried it now and it still doesn't even hit the method when I press the button "Use Photo"