# Swift3 warning imagePickerController nearly matches

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

While converting from old version of swift I am getting a warning for

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: AnyObject])
```

The warning is

> Instance method
>   'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly
>   matches optional requirement
>   'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol
>   UIImagePickerControllerDelegae

The problem here is is that as far as my eyes tell, what it complains about and what it says nearly matches are 100% the same. How do I solve this warning?

Comment: `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {`

Comment: You are using `AnyObject` where should be `Any`

Comment: Thank you - I will accept answer if any of you make it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/40480876/2303865

Answer (score 7):

In newer swift version, method should be

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

then, warning doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct answer in Swift 5.2

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
     let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
     imgRoom.image  = tempImage
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```